# Spring Transaction Management Rollback after delete statement

Tags: java, spring

I am writing a Test class to test cases of sql injection attacks.I wanted to use Spring's Transaction Management support.So i created this basic Config Class:

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class Config {

    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource(){
        EmbeddedDatabaseBuilder builder = new EmbeddedDatabaseBuilder();

        builder.setType(EmbeddedDatabaseType.H2).addScripts("tables.sql", "import.sql");

        return builder.build();
    }

    @Bean
    public TransactionManager transactionManager(DataSource dataSource) {
        return new DataSourceTransactionManager(dataSource);
    }

}
```

When i run all of my tests,some of them pass(that shouldn't) because they see the results of actions of other test methods,which i wanted to eliminate with use of transactions.Am i doing something wrong here?
Below i have two methods.When i run both of them,and if the sqlInjectionModifyingDatabase is executed first,the second method passes(goes inside if,which it shouldn't) because all of the data delete from the first method are commited.

```
@Test
public void sqlInjectionModifyingDatabase() throws SQLException {

    String[] credentials = getInputsWithModification();

    String sql_query = "SELECT 1 FROM CREDENTIALS WHERE user_name = '" + credentials[0]
            + "' AND pass_word = '" + credentials[1]+"'";

    int numOfClientsAfter = 0,numOfClientsBefore = 0;

    try(Connection connection = dataSource.getConnection()){
        ResultSet resultSet = connection.createStatement()
                .executeQuery("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM CREDENTIALS");

        resultSet.next();
        numOfClientsBefore = resultSet.getInt(1);
        System.out.println("Users in the system before executing sql injected query : "
                + numOfClientsBefore);


        dataSource.getConnection().createStatement()
                .executeQuery(sql_query);


        try(ResultSet resultSet2 = connection.createStatement()
                .executeQuery("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM CREDENTIALS")){
            resultSet2.next();
            numOfClientsAfter = resultSet2.getInt(1);
            System.out.println("Users in the system after executing sql injected query : "+ numOfClientsAfter);

        }

    }

    if (numOfClientsAfter != numOfClientsBefore) {
        fail("The number of clients changed.");
    }

}

@Test
public void sqlInjectionSolution() throws SQLException {
    String[] credentials = getInputsWithInjection();

    try(PreparedStatement preparedStatement = dataSource.getConnection()
                        .prepareStatement
                                ("SELECT 1 FROM CREDENTIALS WHERE user_name = ? AND pass_word = ?"))
    {

        preparedStatement.setString(1, credentials[0]);
        preparedStatement.setString(2, credentials[1]);
        ResultSet resultSet = preparedStatement.executeQuery();

        if (!resultSet.next()) {
            System.err.println("Wrong credentials");
            return;
        }

        fail();
        System.out.println("Welcome");

    }



}
```

The signature of the Test Class is as follows:

```
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = Config.class)
@Transactional
public class SqlInjection{...}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the problem is that even though you are using `@Transactional`, you are getting database connections yourself and hereby completely circumventing Spring's `@Transactional` support.

```
   try(Connection connection = dataSource.getConnection()){
```

You have a couple of options:

1. Use the [`JdbcTemplate`](https://spring.io/guides/gs/relational-data-access/) to execute your queries, it will take part in Spring's transactions.
2. Use the [`TransactionTemplate`](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-programmatic-transaction-management) with a `TransactionalCallback`.
3. Rather raw, you could also use Spring's `DataSourceUtils.getConnection(dataSource)` instead of `dataSource.getConnection()`, which `JdbcTemplate` uses internally, and which also respects transactional boundaries. You should call `DataSourceUtils.releaseConnection` after you are done.

(Side-Note: I also wrote [Java Database Transaction Management](https://www.marcobehler.com/books/1-java-database-connections-transactions), which explains these different patterns in detail).